# External Webcam Detected by cheese but not working(webcam- fingers 720p)

Tags: drivers, server, 22.04, webcam, camera

"My question is about that ,I am using an external webcam by fingers it has resolution of 720. When I am connecting my webcam on my laptop it detects in cheese but video is displayed and get stuck, starts flickering and get's hanged too.But it was working when i had ubuntu 20.04 in my laptop.
The same issue was happening in windows by installing its drivers, perfectly working there." All this happened after my laptop was formatted, also I installed new versions.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:a060 Quanta Computer, Inc. HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1124:2925 Jieli Technology USB PHY 2.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. You need the driver for the camera. Check the makers web site for the driver. If there is not one you MIGHT be out of luck.

Comment: But it was working when i had ubuntu 20.04 in my pc

Comment: You should add that to the question with the edit command.